# How to mathematically define a torus in a volume

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, mathematics

Using the node editor and Cycles, how can I define a material that looks like a torus? This is useful in order to render a really smooth torus, without needing to a bazillion vertices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the following node setup:

[image]

The formula which I implemented in order to achieve this can be found in the [Wikipedia article for Torus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry). Note that this only works for tori whose big radius is greater than or equal to it's small radius.

Comment: I don't see how this renders a smooth torus? If I add scatter and really small step size I don't get a smooth torus. What is the advantage of this? Is this somehow better than torus from verts?

Comment: @Jerryno Mainly, it's more fun :D What do you mean? it looks fine with an emission shader... Also, I think you get a lower memory usage as well...

Comment: Well with emission its fine but I was looking forward to make a volumetric smooth shaded torus, no luck yet still fiddling with this..

Comment: Wait, it works fine for me! How are you connecting the setup?

Comment: Yup, and also multiplied it a lot to get a solid surface, then set step size to 0.001

Comment: Screenshot? Mine looks like http://imgur.com/hjyNGhd

Comment: Well you can't see any shading on yours, needs a lamp. Mine: http://imgur.com/PjfqAbu moire all over surface and not nice shading at all. I will play with this another time.

Comment: tested, approuved! Playing alone Someonewithpc ? :)